# TA-Lib returns result just for 1 period

Tags: c#

I want to calculate the MFI for 14 24 hour periods.
Im loading 15 24h periods.
In the output I have only 1 MFI value and all other lines the value is 0.
Ta-Lib returns "Success". What am I doing wrong?
The same thing happens when I try to calculate other things like atr for example.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using TicTacTec.TA.Library;


namespace MFITest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://poloniex.com/public?command=returnChartData&currencyPair=XMR_DASH&start=1502020458&end=1503350000&period=86400"); // Get 15 periods
            request.Method = "GET";
            string reply; 
            using (var response = request.GetResponse())
            {
                using (StreamReader responseStream = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    reply = responseStream.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
            dynamic chartDataDynamic = JArray.Parse(reply);
            var high = new double[chartDataDynamic.Count];
            for (int i = 0; i < chartDataDynamic.Count; i++)
            {
                high[i] = (double)chartDataDynamic[i]["high"];
            }
            var low = new double[chartDataDynamic.Count];
            for (int i = 0; i < chartDataDynamic.Count; i++)
            {
                low[i] = (double)chartDataDynamic[i]["low"];
            }
            var open = new double[chartDataDynamic.Count];
            for (int i = 0; i < chartDataDynamic.Count; i++)
            {
                open[i] = (double)chartDataDynamic[i]["open"];
            }
            var close = new double[chartDataDynamic.Count];
            for (int i = 0; i < chartDataDynamic.Count; i++)
            {
                close[i] = (double)chartDataDynamic[i]["close"];
            }
            var volume = new double[chartDataDynamic.Count];
            for (int i = 0; i < chartDataDynamic.Count; i++)
            {
                volume[i] = (double)chartDataDynamic[i]["volume"];
            }
            var startIdx = 0;
            var endIdx = high.Length - 1;
            var period = 14; 
            var outBegIdx = -1;
            var outNbElement = -1;
            var taLibOutDoubles = new double[endIdx];
            var retCode = Core.Mfi(startIdx, endIdx, high, low, close, volume, period, out outBegIdx, out outNbElement,
                taLibOutDoubles);
            Console.WriteLine(retCode);
            var tools = new Tools();
            foreach (var line in taLibOutDoubles)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(line);
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

taLibOutDoubles Output:>

1. 51.2076586152978
2. 0
3. 0
4. 0
5. 0
6. 0
7. 0
8. 0
9. 0
10. 0
11. 0
12. 0
13. 0
14. 0

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I have misunderstood MFI, but as per this: http://www.chart-formations.com/indicators/mfi.aspx?cat=momentum Money flow index is an aggregation index which will yield in one figure if you give 14 periods as input.

If you would change period e.g. 2 you would get the array populated, however, looks like 14 days is by far most common.
Resulting MFI `51` shows that it was neither oversold or overbought in given period.

Looks like this is remotely linked with C# and could rather be placed in https://quant.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: If i change the period to 2 the output is:
https://ybin.me/p/4fb301f6e9dbf9e4#HEzKjeN1Fn4qDQ/BQC91cDEE9lSdneonujDD7eUvsH8=

Comment: @B-Z yes, so this as per formula gives you 24 hour MFIs for given each day. Zeros at the beginning and end is due to fact that for first there is no start index and for last there is no end index respectively. Value 2 is the minimum parameter value.

Comment: ,so if I change the ticker period request from 24 hours to 5 minutes ( period=86400 to period=300 ) what period I should use with TA-Lib to get every 5 minute MFI index? Im little confused because it outputs a lot of lines with 0 value.
https://ybin.me/p/a99637f10057fd5b#pYJxI7YHb/ty5bpv7wNxMMRKRmZIq2Le28qiBVAEa4Y=

Comment: @B-Z yes, I think result is fine. Take a look at the input data here https://poloniex.com/public?command=returnChartData&currencyPair=XMR_DASH&start=1502020458&end=1503350000&period=300. Period is so small that the change is not present when going from one 5 min period to other. This should explain constant values of 0 and 100 in MFI.

Comment: But when I use the 5 minute period the last 13 lines are always 0.